# Plupload fail on 2MB picture

Tags: php, plupload

I have a [PLupload](http://www.plupload.com) working on my server.
I changed the `fastcgi` value `MaxRequestLen` to not have fatal error when using bigger files.
The max upload size is 10MB, the chunk size is 10MB, the memory limit is set to 40M and time limit set to 0.

- when i upload a 2MB picture, it shows an error message with a title `HTTP Error.`.
- my error log for this Ajax request is empty.

However, smaller pictures are uploaded successfully.

Where do I need to look for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What does the error log say.

Normally you set the max upload size in the php settings.

Comment: now i found out, that its stopping on first proccess call 

`echo 'x';
    $foo->Process($upload_path);
    echo 'x';`
i got response with just one 'x'. i repeat that smaller files under 1MB is uploading well.

post_max_size: 10M
upload_max_filesize: 10M